# Loop variable in v-for is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can the loop variable in a `v-for` loop be undefined? If it was undefined, why is the loop entered at all?
The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

This is the code in the template:

```html
<!-- loop through measurements -->
<div class="test-container" v-for="(measurement, m) in printData.measurements" :key="m">

  <div class="gray-ribbon page-break" v-if="testId">
    {{ measurement.title }}
    <span class="ribbon-sub-title">{{ testNoOfCount(m) }}</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

The debugger shows this:

[image: debugger screenshot]

So the loop index variable is defined (= 0), we are in the first iteration.

`pintData.measurements` is an array of 2 objects defined in the component's props, both have a title property. And if I let the debugger continue, the breakpoint is hit again with `m = 1` and `measurement` still being undefined...

This is `printData` as shown in the Vue inspector:
[image]

Vue version 3.2.26, component is using the Options API.

Comment: This is Vue, not JavaScript. There is no `<v-for="x of y">`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

The parent component (A) needs to load the measurement info from a REST server; the component with the error (B) was initialised too early, before the data was available. A set B's properties with a computed property that is an empty array until the server response is received. I do not know why Vue enters the loop at all, but preventing B's loading with a `v-if` until the server response is there solved the problem.